# disabling anonymous access in IIS 8.5 causes redirect to /account/login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, iis-8.5

I have several sites in a staging environment that should not allow public access.
When I disable anonymous access in iis 8.5 it writes to the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

which causes a redirect to the specified url.  This, of course invokes the error page as there isn't a login page.  This is further aggravated by some sites actually having forms auth enabled which now gets overridden causing additional issues.

On this same server (windows server 2012 r2) are other sites where disabling anonymous access does not write to the web.config.  The only real difference between the sites is the version of .net.

Sites that get entries written to the web.config are all targeting .net 4.0 whereas the ones that work properly target .net 4.5 and 4.5.1

Could the version of .net be the issue?  Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: What happens if you just manually remove the <forms line? Does that not resolve your problem? Are you deploying under the same 'Default Site'? It may actually just be inheriting from the parent if you have other sites with forms auth - if you create an new IIS application, you could avoid that.

Comment: Each site is deployed to its own instance within iis.  manually removing the entry in the web.config does not stop it from redirecting.  In fact removing it, just changes the redirect url

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information - like screenshots of your IIS setup, because that redirect should only happen if forms auth is enabled on the site. I assume you are seeing a 302 response and not a 401 before hitting the login page? I have never seen it automatically get added, to a mode="Windows" auth element. Do you have a transformation in the ASP.Net application for Web.config perhaps?